# Why subscribe event of dropdown is being called on load knockoutJs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select, subscribe

This may be a basic question but I am unable to get any solution.

I am trying to show a list of formats in a dropdown. I am using knockout binding to do so. `I want to show a specific value initially`.

When user selects some other value from the dropdown it should show the selected value (which is working fine).

On selecting any option I want to get the selected value so that I can send it to the server. I am using `subscribe`for that.

Below is my code:

```js
var obj = this;
obj.formatArray = ko.observableArray([{'text' : "MM/DD/YYYY"},
  {'text' : "MM-DD-YYYY"},
  {'text' : "MM.DD.YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD/MM/YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD-MM-YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD.MM.YYYY"}]);

var format1 = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

obj.formatArrayDefault = ko.observable({text :format1});

obj.formatArrayDefault.subscribe(function(newValue){
alert("default value " + format1);
alert("new value in subscribe " + newValue.text);
});

ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select class="" data-bind="options:formatArray(),optionsText:'text',value:formatArrayDefault"></select>
```

You can run the above snippet and check, `alert` inside `subscribe` is coming on loading and changing the value to be displayed to the `first value in the array`.

Why subscribe is called on load and why the value is changed to first value?

What mistake I am doing?

If the question is duplicate can someone give link to the solution (I searched here but could not get any solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want the value of the dropdown after any change.

just take a observable and set it as value it the drop down and initially it will be blank and in your subscribe function just add a line of comparision if the value of drop down is empty dont call the alert function.

```js
var obj = this;
obj.formatArray = ko.observableArray([{'text' : "MM/DD/YYYY"},
{'text' : "MM-DD-YYYY"},
{'text' : "MM.DD.YYYY"},
{'text' : "DD/MM/YYYY"},
{'text' : "DD-MM-YYYY"},
{'text' : "DD.MM.YYYY"}]);

var format1 = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
obj.initialLoad = true;

obj.formatArrayDefault = ko.observable(format1);

obj.formatArrayDefault.subscribe(function(newValue){

if(obj.initialLoad) {
 obj.initialLoad = false;
 }
 else {
  alert("Hello");   
  }
  });

  ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select class="projectUserAccess workflowSetOptions" data-bind="options:formatArray(),optionsText:'text',value:formatArrayDefault"></select>
```

===EDIT===

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var model = {
        selectedType: 2 //default Type
    };
    
    var viewModel = {
        selectedType: ko.observable(model.selectedType)
        , availableTypes: ko.observableArray([
            { Label: 'Type1', Code: 1 }
            , { Label: 'Type2', Code: 2 }
            , { Label: 'Type3', Code: 3 }
        ])
    };
                
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#content")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <select data-bind="value: selectedType, options: availableTypes, optionsText: 'Label', optionsValue: 'Code', optionsCaption: 'Please select...'"></select><br/>
    
    You've selected Type: <span data-bind="text: selectedType"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to show a default value. It can not be blank. That is the requirement.

Comment: then instead of undefined use that default value to compare to not call the subscribe function

Comment: That will not help. :( 
See my edited code snippet. Inside subscribe, it has changed the value to first value from the array of formats.

Comment: Show the edited answer. Hope it will now help you... :)

Comment: It changed the value in the dropdown to the initial value (mm/dd/yyyy). :( I want to show the default value over there (dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: your problem was on load the function is called which is solved i think

Comment: Yes your answer solved one of the issues. My question is `Why subscribe is called on load and why the value is changed to first value?`. Both of the issues I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hey! Thanx pal!! That is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains plain objets. In javascript, object comparison works like this:

```
var obj1 = { a: 1 };
var obj2 = { a: 1 };

console.log(obj1 === obj2); // false
console.log(obj1 === obj1); // true
```

It checks the actual object instance that is referenced by a variable, not the way it looks. Many libraries contain a "deepEquals" function that you can use to check if two objects actually *look* similar, but knockout doesn't use such a mechanism.

So when you set your initial selection, its value might be *similar* to the object at `formatArray()[0]`, but knockout won't be able to mach the two together. I.e.:

```
obj.formatArrayDefault() === obj.formatArray()[1]; // false
```

Now, when applying bindings, knockout tries to solve the mismatch between selection and source data. It can't find an `<option>` element to match with the selection that is passed to the `value` binding.

It has to render a selected option, so it defaults to the first one. This is when your initial object gets replaced by `formatArray()[0]` and the subscription is triggered.

Here's a solution: we put an actual reference to the first object in our initial value!

```js
var obj = this;
obj.formatArray = ko.observableArray([{'text' : "MM/DD/YYYY"},
  {'text' : "MM-DD-YYYY"},
  {'text' : "MM.DD.YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD/MM/YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD-MM-YYYY"},
  {'text' : "DD.MM.YYYY"}]);

var format1 = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

obj.formatArrayDefault = ko.observable(obj.formatArray()[1]);

obj.formatArrayDefault.subscribe(function(newValue){
  console.log("default value " + format1);
  console.log("new value in subscribe " + newValue.text);
});

ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select class="" data-bind="options:formatArray(),optionsText:'text',value:formatArrayDefault"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)